# Rounding a vector so that all resulting elements are different

Tags: r, vector, rounding

I'm looking for a routine that would round a vector by the "necessary" number of digits so that all elements are still distinguishable. My first attempt looks like this:

```
discr.round <- function(x) {
  digits <- ceiling(-min(log10(diff(sort(x)))))
  round(x, digits)
}

discr.round(c(12.336, 12.344))
# [1] 12.336 12.344
discr.round(c(12.336, 12.347))
# [1] 12.34 12.35
discr.round(c(10, 25, 39))
# [1] 10 20 40
discr.round(c(1.2345679, 1.2345681))
# [1] 1.234568 1.234568
discr.round(c(1.23456789, 1.23456791))
# [1] 1.234568 1.234568
```

I need this to format a vector of floating-point numbers using "few" decimal places.

How would this kind of rounding be called? Is there a "standard" implementation of this or a similar logic, in base R or a package?

**EDIT**: I need this for pairs, but the code should generalize to vectors of arbitrary length. If the numbers are exactly equal, they do not need to be discriminated.

Comment: Always pairs of numbers? Or longer vectors as well? Are the numbers ever exactly equal?

Comment: @Thomas: See edit. Good catch about equal numbers -- here, of course, digits will be `+Inf` in my implementation.

Comment: What's more, what if you have two equal irrational numbers like 1/7. How many digits do you want to print?

Comment: I hope it's okay that I added two more examples, which I assume you would want handled better than your current implementation.

Comment: @flodel: `discr.round(c(1/7, 1/6))` prints `0.14 0.17`, that's fine with me.

Comment: I was asking about `discr.round(c(1/7, 1/7))`

Comment: @flodel: Sorry, missed that point. How about `0`?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, that's fine. The behavior you show is probably due to R's rounding, see e.g. `discr.round(c(1.79, 1.81))`. Won't happen if we also `format()` with the necessary number of digits.

Comment: IMHO, your function should have an optional argument for the maximum number of digits to be printed after the decimal point. That arg can be used to answer my question and @Thomas' issue as well. Make `digits <- min(digits, max.digits)` and use `format`.

Comment: Wondering about converting to character strings and returning substrings up to the first mismatch.  Probably a lot slower, and would be more of a truncation than a rounding operation.

Comment: I'm really foggy this AM, but doesn't flodel's comment about `format` and min number of digits to actually display solve the display error in the examples Thomas added? The actual stored values are correct.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I had the same though about character strings, but figured it would be really inefficient for long vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options(digits=12) # Part of the problem is that your default digits = 7,
                   #   so you won't see any digits beyond that.
                   #  If you put too many (e.g, 22), you'll get floating point imprecision

#  Note the behavior for rounding off a 5 under ?round:
#  "IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’."

# digits needed to distinguish between two nonequal elements
diff.dec.places <- function(x, y){
  delta <- abs(x - y)
  dec.place <- -ceiling(log10(abs(delta))) # your idea here was correct
  print(paste0("The elements (",x," & ",y,") differ in the ",
               10^-dec.place,"'s place."))
  if(round(x, dec.place)==round(y, dec.place)){
    print("But we add another sig. figure so they do not round to the same number.")
    dec.place <- dec.place + 1
  } 
  print(paste("The elements will round to",round(x, dec.place),'&',round(y, dec.place)))
  dec.place
}


# formula for arbitrary number of elements:
discr.round <- function(x){

  #- Find minimum-magnitude difference and which elements possess it: 
  #-   Create upper triangle of difference matrix of elements of vector with itself
  d <- abs(outer(x,x,"-"))
  d[lower.tri(d, diag=T)] <- NA
  #-   Return the smallest-magnitude difference and indices of elements forming it
  m <- min(d, na.rm=T)     
  if(m != 0){
    #- Round to number of dec places required to distinguish the closest elements
    e <- x[which(d==m, arr.ind=T)]
    round(x, diff.dec.places(e[1],e[2]))
  }
  else{
    print("Closest elements are equal.") 
    x
  }
}


discr.round(c(12.336, 12.344))
# [1] 12.336 12.344
discr.round(c(12.336, 12.347))
# [1] 12.34 12.35
discr.round(c(10, 25, 39))
# [1] 10 20 40
discr.round(c(1.2345679, 1.2345681))
# [1] 1.2345679 1.2345681
discr.round(c(1.23456789, 1.23456791))
# [1] 1.23456789 1.23456791
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my very slow reply. Does the code change when I assume that `x` is sorted?

Comment: If `x` is assumed sorted then you would not need to calculate the upper-triangle difference matrix since the minimum difference would be always between adjacent elements of `x`. Instead, it would be faster to use `d <-diff(x)` and work from there.